# Error Fetching http headers SOAP Client

Tags: php, apache, soap

I am using a SOAP client for placing order in Magento (PHP) and Getting Error Fetching http headers while hitting that webservice.

When I restart httpd then the error disappears and I am able to place order again and again

**What I tried**

default_socket_timeout :  120

**Code Snippet of SOAP CLIENT**

```
$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2,
                           array(
                                'trace' =>true,
                                'connection_timeout' => 500000,
                                'keep_alive' => false,
                            )
 );
```

checked around the httpd logs and found following

```
[Mon Oct 17 01:50:24 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/store/app/etc/local.xml
[Mon Oct 17 01:53:53 2016] [notice] child pid 28113 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Oct 17 01:57:52 2016] [notice] child pid 29400 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Oct 17 02:01:14 2016] [notice] child pid 29401 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Oct 17 02:02:50 2016] [notice] child pid 29398 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Oct 17 02:05:38 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/store/app/etc/local.xml
[Mon Oct 17 02:06:40 2016] [notice] child pid 28180 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Please let me know if any other information I can provide to track this out.

SOAP trace is not showing anything for me. this problem is with this web service only , my soap client is working fine with others.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing php.ini file `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1` and change it to `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0`